# Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'

Tags: sass

I'm flowing the ROR 4 tutorials , There is a chapter mentioned about Compiling Sass to CSS . I modified (`#logo:hover and #footer:hover`)  to  `& :hover`  But error occurred

```
Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'.
 (in/Users/snailwalker/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:54)
```

My SCSS:

```
/* header */
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
}
& :hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, I have:


&::selection {
    background: $color-base;
}
&::-webkit-selection {
    background: $color-base;
}
&::-moz-selection {
    background: $color-base;
}


when I remove this part of code this is working without any problem!

I don't know what is the reason

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you need to move that inside the curly braces for logo.

Like this:

```
# logo {
    float: left;
    ...
  &:hover {
    color: color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `&` has to be nested inside of a css/scss rule so:

```
.my_class {
    css-rule: value;
    another-css-rule: value;

    &:hover {
        css-hover-rule: value;
    }
 }
```

The way you have it Sass doesnt know what the `&` is for. 
The above is the same as having:

```
.my_class {
    some rules.....
}

.my_class:hover {
    some hover rules....
}
```