# how to apply same style to different deep level selectors with same parent path

Tags: css, sass

I want to set some border color to multiple form elements. I have below code

```
.home .form-warn .form__text input, 
.home .form-warn .form__text select, 
.home .form-warn .form__text textarea {
    border-color: #e2231a;
}
```

I am trying to write in one liner code something like below

```
.home .form-warn .form__text [input, select, textarea] {
    border-color: #e2231a;
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner per se, but you can achieve this with the following SASS:

```
.home .form-warn .form__text
  & input, select, textarea
    border-color: #e2231a;
```

[The `&` keyword being, well, key here!](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting below error  

`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

  & input, textarea {
 ^
      Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'.
`

Comment: Could be an issue with indentation, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555024/base-level-rules-cannot-contain-the-parent-selector-referencing-character

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outputting a ton of CSS why not add a simple class to the inputs and then style that?

```
.form__text .input--border { border-color: #e2231a; }
```